# ajax post method not working in vb.net

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I am using jquery so using ajax to post data, but for some reason when i click on submit, the page doesnt go from aspx to aspx.vb on the back side.
here's my code -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnsave").click(function() {
          var firstname = $("#" + '<%=firstname.ClientID%>').val(); 
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "student.aspx/new_class",
              data: "firstname="+ firstname + ";",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function() {                     
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

new_class is my webmethod in the vb.net side. Now if i put an alert in the btnsave onclick function, i see the firstname value in the alert. But the page does not call the new_class function after that.
Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: What is setup on the server side to interpret `somepage.aspx/somemethod` as a method call for the page?.. This is not native functionality of ASP.net.

Comment: Two things: 1) Your web method URL looks odd.  Is this perhaps an MVC implementation on an old IIS or something of that nature?  2) What happens when you call that URL manually (both on the client and on the server)?

Comment: whenever i clck on accept, it tells me to login, even if i have logged in. Anyways, Quintin, you said my setup is wrong. Could you direct me to some documentation, so i could work on that? its IIS7 with asp.net and vb.net in back. No MVC. My only goal is to pass data to the back end code. If anyone feels another method is better, please do tell.

Comment: have a look at this meta link to solve your login problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That URL is incorrect for mapping to a method on the server-side code.

I assume you're trying to call a method called `new_class` in `student.aspx.vb`.  Is this correct?

What you'll want to do is create a separate page for this request.  Maybe something like `student_ajax.aspx` or something of that nature.  How you organize it is up to you.  The simplest way to go about doing what you're trying to do is to have the `new_class` logic be the `Page_Load` logic in the new page.  In that method you'll generate the JSON (which I'm assuming you're doing manually and correctly, but that's for a different question if it comes up) to return to the client.

Note, however, that in that page you'll need to do some trickery.  First, get rid of all of the HTML in the page itself.  You want to return *only* JSON, not wrapped in any HTML.  Then, when you're generating the response string in the code-behind logic, you'll want to set the header to the proper headers and output the string:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Response.Write(myJSONString)
Response.End()
```

Note that this was all freehand, so there may be a detail or two missing in this implementation.  And I *know* there are more elegant ways to do this.  I'm sure you can find a tutorial or two on Google.  Essentially what you're trying to do is create a custom handler on the server for an AJAX request which returns JSON data.